# Returning array from simple function is empty

Tags: php

I have the following function:

```
function getUser($user_id){

    $mysqli = dbConnect();

    $gu = "select * from users where user_id = '$user_id'";
    $ru = $mysqli->query($gu);

    $user = $ru->fetch_array();

    return $user;
}
```

Which is called eg:

```
$user_id =  $_SESSION[user_id];

getUser($user_id);
```

Then I want to simply echo fields i want, e.g. name. But, when I try the following, it returns empty

```
echo "users name is $user['name']"; // returns: users name is
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE** Also tried the following  but still empty:

```
function getUser($user_id){

    $mysqli = dbConnect();

    $gu = "select * from users where user_id = '$user_id'";
    $ru = $mysqli->query($gu);

    $user = array();
    while($row = $ru->fetch_array()) {
        $user[] = $row;
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: You doesn't store the result of `getUser()`. Check the answer of @CodeBird

Comment: The comments/answers already posted are correct. A couple of other things: 1) What is the type of the `user_id` column? You're querying it like it's a string type. 2) Have you tried checking into the return value of your `fetch_array()` call? `var_dump()` or `print_r()` if you've no debugger handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your line:

```
getUser($user_id);
```

should be:

```
$user=getUser($user_id);
```

This way you'll be setting $user to the array the getUser returns, then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes when printing an array, you `echo` may needed to be like:

```
echo "users name is $user[name]";
```